# My commits do not appear on my contribion table on Github. What to do?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github, commit, github-desktop

I have a problem with my GitHub contributions table. The things is that when I commit from VS Code the Django project using GitHub Desktop, the commits do not appear on my contribution table. The commit is made to the other branch than "main". I have two emails on GitHub, one is personal and other is university's for getting PRO version. So, the email is set right in GitHub Desktop as well. But my commits still don't appear on contributions table though they should (I think) when I push. When I commit from Android Studio using terminal it does appear and everything is fine. My repository is also getting updated, but the table is empty. Can you please help to fix it?

I tried to check if the emails match on GitHub Desktop and GitHub and it's fine, the default is the university's email though the personal email is the alternative. I don't know what else to check since everything else seems fine.

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/managing-contribution-settings-on-your-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile#commits "_The commits were made:
In the repository's default branch_"